# Counting differences between two strings

Tags: python

I'm trying to count the number of differences between two imported strings (seq1 and seq2, import code not listed), but am getting no result when running the program.  I want the output to read something like "2 differences."  Not sure where I'm going wrong...

```
def difference (seq1, seq2):    
    count = 0
    for i in seq1:
        if seq1[i] != seq2[i]:
            count += 1
        return (count)
    print (count, "differences")
```

Comment: count = sum(1 for a, b in zip(seq1, seq2) if a != b)
print (count)

Worked great!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could do this pretty flatly with a generator expression

```
count = sum(1 for a, b in zip(seq1, seq2) if a != b)
```

If the sequences are of a different length, then you may consider the difference in length to be difference in content (I would).  In that case, tag on an extra piece to account for it

```
count = sum(1 for a, b in zip(seq1, seq2) if a != b) + abs(len(seq1) - len(seq2))
```

Another weirdish way to write that which takes advantage of `True` being `1` and `False` being `0` is:

```
sum(a != b for a, b in zip(seq1, seq2))+ abs(len(seq1) - len(seq2))
```

`zip` is a python builtin that allows you to iterate over two sequences at once.  It will also terminate on the shortest sequence, observe:

```
>>> seq1 = 'hi'
>>> seq2 = 'world'
>>> for a, b in zip(seq1, seq2):
...     print('a =', a, '| b =', b)
... 
a = h | b = w
a = i | b = o
```

This will evaluate similar to `sum([1, 1, 1])` where each `1` represents a difference between the two sequences.  The `if a != b` filter causes the generator to only produce a value when `a` and `b` differ.

Comment: It returns `1`  tested on `hey` and `hello`.

Comment: @howaboutNO hm, from OP it seemed the sequences were of the same length but good point, I will adjust

Comment: use itertools.izip_longest :)

Comment: @Hackaholic Specifically for strings that could work but would need an extra check before comparing in the filter. `if a is not None and b is not None and a != b`

Comment: yep fillchar must be unique, that not should not be in strings

Comment: the third code line end should change to abs(len(seq1) - len(seq2)

Comment: If you need the string lengths to be made the same, the built-in string function zfill() will let pad zeroes to your shorter string.

Answer (score 2):

When you say `for i in seq1` you are iterating over the characters, not the indexes.  You can use `enumerate` by saying `for i, ch in enumerate(seq1)` instead.

Or even better, use the standard function `zip` to go through both sequences at once.

You also have a problem because you `return` before you `print`.  Probably your `return` needs to be moved down and unindented.

Answer (score 1):

in your script there are to mistakes

1. "i" should be integer, not char
2. "return" should be in function the same level as print, not in cycle "for"
3. try not to use "print" in such way in functions

here is working version:

```
def difference (seq1, seq2):    
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(seq1)):
        if seq1[i] != seq2[i]:
            count += 1
    return (count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct code would be:

```
def difference(seq1, seq2):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(seq1)):
        if seq1[i] != seq2[i]:
            count += 1
    return count
```

First the return statement is done at the end of the function, therefore it should not be part of the for loop or the for loop would just run once.
Second the for loop wasn't correct because you weren't really telling giving the for loop an integer, therefore the correct code would be to give it a range the length of seq1, so:

```
for i in range(len(seq1)):
```

Answer (score 0):

So I had to do what you are asking to do and I came up with a very simple solution.  Mine is a little different because I check the string to see which is bigger and put them in the correct variable for comparison later.  All done with Vanilla python:

```
#Declare Variables
a='Here is my first string'
b='Here is my second string'
notTheSame=0
count=0

#Check which string is bigger and put the bigger string in C and smaller string in D
if len(a) >= len(b):
    c=a
    d=b
if len(b) > len(a):
    d=a
    c=b

#While the counter is less than the length of the longest string, compare each letter.
while count < len(c):
    if count == len(d):
        break
    if c[count] != d[count]:
        print(c[count] + " not equal to " + d[count])
        notTheSame = notTheSame + 1
    else:
        print(c[count] + " is equal to " + d[count])
    count=count+1

#the below output is a count of all the differences + the difference between the 2 strings
print("Number of Differences: " + str(len(c)-len(d)+notTheSame))
```